# Products fetching depend on price selection using php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display products depend on price selection by user, here I am facing issue here is my code please tell me how to solve this.

I have created sql fiddle please check this link [clickhere](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e2d0/3)

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO products (`id`, `name`, `description`, `category_id`) VALUES 
(1, 'Samsung Galaxy S4', 'Samsung Galaxy S4 GT- I9500', 6),
(2, 'Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo', 'Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo', 6),
(3, 'Samsung Galaxy S Duos 3', 'Samsung Galaxy S', 6),
(4, 'Samsung Galaxy Grand 2', 'Samsung Galaxy Grand 2', 6);

INSERT INTO products (`id`, `name`, `description`, `category_id`) VALUES 
(5, 'Samsung Galaxy TAB', 'Samsung Galaxy TAB', 7),
(6, 'Samsung Galaxy TAB 2', 'Samsung Galaxy TAB 2', 7),
(7, 'Samsung Galaxy TAB 3', 'Samsung Galaxy TAB 3', 7),
(8, 'Samsung Galaxy TAB 4', 'Samsung Galaxy TAB 4', 7);

CREATE TABLE price (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO price (`id`, `product_id`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 1, 6930),
(2, 1, 7000),
(3, 2, 12490),
(4, 2, 13000),
(5, 3, 6400),
(6, 3, 7000),
(7, 4, 14300),
(8, 4, 15000),
(9, 5, 10000),
(10,5, 11000),
(11,6, 12000),
(12,6, 13000),
(13,7, 14000),
(14,7, 15000),
(15,8, 20000),
(16,8, 22000);

select DISTINCT p.*, p.category_id as pid FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN price as pr ON pr.product_id=p.id where pr.price >= 5001 AND pr.price <= 10000 OR pr.price >= 10001 AND pr.price <= 20000 AND p.category_id IN (6);
```

When I run this qquery my intention is products should come with in the category_id of '6' but here I am getting 7 also. please see live example in sql fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap this condition in parenthesis, i have tested your fiddle

```
where (pr.price >= 5001 AND pr.price <= 10000 OR  pr.price >= 10001 AND pr.price <= 20000)
```

Comment: Thank You It's working... I will do click on accept with in few minutes.